# How to have WordPress comment moderation emails go ONLY to the site admin

Tags: wordpress, notifications, comments, admin

We have our site setup so that in order for a new users comments to appear on the front-end, they must have their first comment be approved by an admin.   This has proved to be the only effective way to prevent spam comments from blowing up our site.  It's frustrating, but it works.

The problem?

When email notifications are sent out telling the Admin that there are comments for them to moderate..... the post author is also getting the same email.   This is essentially spamming all our post authors who have to deal with getting these notifications even though they don't actually have any ability to moderate these spam comments.

How can I set up our emails that say, "Please moderate...." so they only go to the site Admin.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked which I found elsewhere on StackOverflow:

```
 /** 
  * Plugin Name: Disable comment/trackback/pingback/MODERATION notifications emails EXCEPT for admins.
  * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/150141/26350
  */

/* add_filter( 'comment_notification_recipients', '__return_empty_array', PHP_INT_MAX ); */
add_filter( 'comment_moderation_recipients', 
    function( $emails )
    {
        // only send notification to the admin:
        return array( get_option( 'admin_email' ) );
    }
, PHP_INT_MAX );
```